# How to add a line break with append in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that I want to add a line break from a document. getElementbyId ("iddiv").appen(And here I add an arrangement with several elements)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ogCH.png)

And my result is this

[result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvRCs.png)

And I've tried to solve in different ways but none works, please help:(

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: use "\n" instead of "br"

Comment: @francovici ya lo hice pero no funciono :( jajjaa y tiene bastante codigo porque es un compilador jjaja por eso no lo subo para que lo ejecuten

Comment: Look at my answer (hablo en inglés por reglas del sitio).

Comment: For moderation purposes, please keep to English only.   Without getting the text translated it makes it more difficult for moderators to know what you have said is against house rules.  Hope you understand!!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append only the element, without making concatenation:

```
document.getElementById('caja2').append(detectar(data2[x]));
document.getElementById('caja2').append(document.createElement('br'));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much this worked spend 3 hours trying to jajajja but seriously thank you very much

Comment: Jajaja, you're very welcome !